# Performance impact of Broker query to retrieve page details with 300-600 rpm on the website

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, brokerquery

We have implemented our application using SDL Web 8.5 and DXA 2.0. The product detail pages in our application needs to be queried from the Broker DB using Broker API. Now, as per existing application standards, we expect around 300-600 requests per minute for these product detail pages. Are there any performance related issues we need to be concerned about in DXA/Web 8.5?

I am not sure this is clear enough, as I am sure this might be quite a vague problem statement. But any help would be really appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Where is the broker query based on?  Generally speaking, you should ensure there is sufficient caching to prevent having to execute tens of broker queries per second. How well caching works depends on the variability of the query.

Comment: The broker query will be based on a group id, with which we might have multiple products tagged. This query would not change much/at all. However, as for the caching strategy, we are yet to decide on that. So,  for caching, what all pointers should we keep in mind, to ensure smooth functioning of our application with 300-600rpm?

Comment: If the query doesn’t vary much per request, caching will be very effective (even with a relatively low TTL) and tens of requests per second doesn’t have to be a problem at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as your question is vague, I am afraid that the answer is also. What you need to do is basically do a stress test. See how your app behaves with this number of requests.

In general, bottleneck can happen in few places:

1. CD microservices - you can scale them up really easily - just add more servers and you are good to go. You can use different scaling strategies for this (scale number of servers with entire CD microservices cluster, or scale each microservice separately, whatever is required from your side)
2. your presentation side can be slow - DXA app. Here you also need to analyze the behavior of it and maybe do some touch ups
3. or the database can get really slow. This probably won't happen, but in any case, you can analyze requests to Broker DB, check query results execution times, and with proper maintenance and scalability make sure that its maximum responsive.